# как передать пароли с своего сайта в txt файл?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как средствами html, отправлять пароли введенные на сайте, отправлялись в `txt` файл, на ПК.

Comment: Возможно, но только при использовании backend. Например c [node.js](https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/2.8.php)

Comment: На чужих сайтах? xD

Comment: А если же это ваш сайт, то у вас полюбому будет сервер, на котором будут лежать файлы сайта и который собственно их раздает, соответственно backend у вас уже есть, вам необходимо написать логику данного действия.

PS Если вам пароли нужны для сверки, а не для чего-то другого используйте Базу Данных.

Comment: Существует семнадцать тысяч тридцать девять способов как украсть пароль у одноклассницы... Почему вы выбираете самый сложый путь... через `html`? Это настолько сложно, что практически невозможно.